# C++ cin Question

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

Okay, I was writing a simple C++ function to combine cin'd strings. I'm working on Linux at the moment, so I don't have the luxury of a simple "getline(cin, input)" command. Here's the code so far:

```
string getLine()          
{
    string dummy;          
    string retvalue;          
    do
    {
        cin << dummy;
        retvalue += dummy;
    } while           
    return retvalue;          
}
```

What I want to know is this: is the prompt actually asking the user for input, or is it still reading from the buffer that was left over because of a space?

Comment: You seem to be missing your while statement in your do/while loop...

Comment: Why can't you use cin's getline member function?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/

Comment: I don't see the connection between being on Linux and lacking a `getline` function. How old is your distribution, that it doesn't come with 1998's standard C++ library? Also, please **copy and paste** your **real code**. It's obvious that's not your real code since there's no condition on the while loop and the `cin` operator is pointing the wrong direction. "The prompt" you refer to isn't doing anything because the code you posted doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `getline` defined for `strings`:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Answer (score 6):

> I'm working on Linux at the moment, so I don't have the luxury of a simple "getline(cin, input)" command.

What's Linux got to do with it? `getline` is standard C++, except it's spelled `cin.getline(input, size[, delimiter])`.

*Edit:* Not deleting this because it's a useful reference, but AraK's post illustrating `std::getline` should be preferred for people who want a `std::string`. `istream`'s `getline` works on a `char *` instead.

Comment: cin.getline(...) is not for strings, it is for char*, good answer though :)

Comment: Does it show that I'm a C programmer who last did C++ ages ago? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the prompt IS actually asking the user for input, but it is expecting a word rather than a line.  That is possibly why it appeared space sensitive to you.

What you want, assuming you want to read more than one line, is this.

```
#include <iostream>
...
std::string sLine;
while(getline(std::cin, sLine)) {
    // process sLine;
}
```

The code had a few other issues.

- cin << dummy  // this should have the >> operator
- The variable should probably be called "word" not "dummy"
- retvalue += dummy;  // you would need to add spaces between words
- } while  // the while test should be some test for end of line

The loop in the question is closer to a word reader.
This would do for that objective.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
...
void getStandardInput(std::list<std::string> & stringList) {

    std::string word;
    while (true) {
         cin >> word;
         if (cin.eof())
              return;
         stringList.push_back(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getline()` is in the `<string>` header

I always forget that.